# Docker Image for maven with OpenJDK 19 is missing

Tags: java, docker, maven, java-19

I am looking at https://openjdk.org/projects/jdk/19/ which seems to indicate that OpenJDK is now Generally Availible as of September 20th 2022. However, when I look at the current maven images (https://hub.docker.com/_/maven) , I find openJDK 17 (https://hub.docker.com/layers/library/maven/3.8.4-openjdk-17/images/sha256-d07c45c45755f0f90b779bad869467e602f1bfff4d0b5eb1ff73f2882bc38187) and openJDK 18 (https://hub.docker.com/layers/library/maven/3.8.7-openjdk-18/images/sha256-1936d70bb3415a0d7e822ed484cdb4974593b195091c145b52ba7775003dc3f0?context=explore)  but I do not see openJdk-19. I searched 'openjdk' https://hub.docker.com/_/maven/tags?page=1&name=openjdk and looked at 'newest' but I cannot find a Java 19. Is there such a openjdk maven artifact perhaps under a different naming scheme? Is there something that I am missing?

Comment: Stay on Java 17 unless you have very good reason to use a non-long term support version. Images will get security updates longer.  When the next LTS version come, upgrade.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It appears that this [project](https://github.com/carlossg/docker-maven) has stopped building Linux images using OpenJDK, due to [discontinuation of the OpenJDK builds those images were based on](https://github.com/docker-library/openjdk/issues/505). It now only provides images using alternative JDK distributions such as Eclipse Temurin and Amazon Corretto. The Temurin images are a suitable replacement for most users.

Also note that, although there are historical [images built with Java 19](https://hub.docker.com/_/maven/tags?page=1&name=19) available, [Java 19 has since been superseded by Java 20](https://endoflife.date/java) and therefore there will not be new images based on Java 19 and the most recent Maven releases. It is generally preferable to use an LTS release of Java such as Java 17. If your project requires a Java version newer than the most recent LTS release, then it’s a good idea to use the most recent version, as interim releases such as Java 18 and 19 may not be supported once a newer version is available. The next upcoming Java release at the time I write this—version 21, due in September 2023—will be an LTS release.

Comment: Thank you so much! Quick follow up - so are https://hub.docker.com/layers/library/maven/3.9.3-amazoncorretto-17/images/sha256-51a8ceaec1ddb3237be298e8f31e794b0e047855d88d8ceae5dbb672606fe4a6  (Correto for Java 17)  and  
 https://hub.docker.com/layers/library/maven/3.9.3-eclipse-temurin-17/images/sha256-6608458bcb7dbe1d53d90c0bd513a3888159d111adae2dbdffc31239bd9d3039 (Temurin Java 17) both replacements for https://hub.docker.com/layers/library/maven/3.8.4-openjdk-17/images/sha256-d07c45c45755f0f90b779bad869467e602f1bfff4d0b5eb1ff73f2882bc38187  (at least at a high level)?

Comment: @HeronAlgoSearch Those Corretto and Temurin images are using a newer version of Maven than the OpenJDK one, but they should be compatible for most uses.

Comment: I notice that the Corretto image is showing known high severity vulnerabilities. I would personally stick with Temurin as a default unless I needed to use Amazon Linux or get support for Corretto from Amazon.